# Regular expression starts with a string but not contain a special character after that

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression which basically matches start of a string but not having a specific character after that. By this I should be achieving same level routes.

Example : Lets say I have the following strings and I need to get routes starting from LAX with no stops.

1. LAX-LAS-JFK
2. LAX-PHX-JFK
3. LAX-JFK
4. LAX-PHX

The regex should match only route 3 and 4.

I have tried this ^LAX-([^-])* and it didn't work for me when I cross checked on https://www.regextester.com/15.

Comment: You need to anchor the pattern to the end as well (of the whole thing, or the line - depends on whether you want to match those test strings individually, or all of them listed under each other), using `$`- otherwise you are allowing for _anything_ after the match. `^LAX-([^-])*$` - https://regex101.com/r/ptZOra/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^LAX(-[A-Z]+){1}$
```

This matches

```
LAX-JFK
LAX-PHX
```

but not

```
LAX-LAS-JFK
LAX-PHX-JFK
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9TcBBS/1)

---

Explanation:

- `^` start
- `$` end
- `{1}` exact number of repetitions of a pattern, in this case `1`

Fun fact: you can replace the `1` by `(number of stops + 1)`, and it will select only the routes with the defined number of stops ([another example](https://regex101.com/r/9TcBBS/2)).

Comment: `{1}` is not essential.

Comment: @revo Agree, it's not essential, but it generalizes better to an arbitrary number of stops. Otherwise one could just take `^LAX-\w+$` or something like that... The question contained something about "same level routes", whatever this means, so I thought it might be better to provide a general solution for an arbitrary number of stops. It does not sacrifice much efficiency either.

Comment: If you want to keep it for the only reason that *it generalizes better...* I'd encourage you to apply it on the other literals as well `^L{1}A{1}X{1}(-{1}[A-Z]{1,}){1}$`

Comment: Nifty fun fact.. could be useful. +1

Comment: @revo the input contained only triples of upper case characters, so the `{1}` in `L{1}A{1}X{1}` are probably not essential. In all examples, the triples were separated by exactly one dash, so nothing is lost if `-{1}` simplified to `-`. If we can be sure that this is IATA, then we should restrict `[A-Z]+` to `[A-Z]{3}`. And I, of course, agree that the last `{1}` can be useful, because it allows to generalize to routes of other length. Thus, `^LAX(-[A-Z]{3}){1}$` seems like a meaningful way to generalize the few examples provided by the OP.

Comment: @revo In contrast to that, I really don't know with what prior distribution over the possible regex-patterns one would have to start to obtain `^L{1}A{1}X{1}(-{1}[A-Z]{1,}){1}$`. It seems to overfit and to require more initial bias.

Comment: I was thinking about generalization too while I was typing that regex!

Comment: @revo Yes, but while you generalized the input, you obtained something that looked more like a 6-dimensional model, whereas my regex (with the explicit remark that only the `{1}` is supposed to be considered a useful variable) is one-dimensional, and the only variable corresponds nicely to the length of the path described by the string. Generalization is one thing, regularization is another...

Comment: Thank You. This is exactly what I was looking for as I require same level routes which might not be direct routes sometimes. I should have elaborated the example a little more for others to get it.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you want to match with strings that only have 1 dash. Perhaps something like this `^(LAX)(-{1})[a-zA-Z]+$` would work? It will check to make sure the string LAX is in the beginning, followed by **one** dash and ending with alphabetical characters.

Comment: You don't need to quantify `-`.

Comment: This answer is correct. It works great for finding direct routes from LAX which is actually the question I have asked. But the solution provided by @Andrey Tyukin works for finding routes from LAX which has a single connection and double connection and so on.